# Spring HazelcastCacheManager, Accessing Hazelcast instance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hazelcast, spring-cache

In my Spring boot app, we have configured `@EnableCaching` with `HazelcastCacheManager` and it working without problem.

But, it is required to access `Hazelcast` instance to use it's other features (distributed locks, distributed computing).

How can I achieve this using the same instance of `Hazelcast` used in `HazelcastCacheManager` (instead of creating new one)?

p.s. First thing came to my mind is registering `Hazelcast` wrapper class as `@Component`, and Auto wiring it to `@Configuration` annotated class using constructor. But I am not sure how things will turn out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [this](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.2/javadoc/com/hazelcast/cache/HazelcastCacheManager.html#getHazelcastInstance--), `HazelcastCacheManager.getHazelcastInstance()`.

Perhaps also then expose the retrieved `HazelcastInstance` as a `@Bean`, then you can inject into the rest of your application and that code need have no awareness of `@EnabledCaching` being present or absent.

Comment: If I expose HazelcastInstance as `@Bean`, will Auto wire pass it to constructor?

Comment: Yes, if you'd rather do it that way. If there's a `HazelcastInstance` bean already that'll be used for the cache manager. If there's not one, one gets made, and you can extract it. Typo in the above link, it'll be [this](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.2/javadoc/com/hazelcast/spring/cache/HazelcastCacheManager.html#getHazelcastInstance--)